# Why does my input convert 'A' and 'B' to 'B' and 'B'

Tags: for-loop

I am working on the following problem: https://dmoj.ca/problem/ccc11s2

For some reason, when I input A, B, A, B, it converts the A's to B's in the code below. Can anyone help me understand what is happening and where my code is going wrong? It seems like the only sum I get is 1 and I don't know where i'm messing up.

#The input will contain the number  () followed by  lines. The  lines are composed of
lines of student responses (with one of A, B, C, D or E on each line), followed by  lines of correct answers (with one of A, B, C, D or E on each line), in the same order as the student answered the questions (that is, if line  is the student response, then line  will contain the correct answer to that question)

n = int(input())

sum = 0

for s in range(n):

```
student = input()
```

for t in range(n):

```
teacher = input()
```

for i in range(len(student)):

```
if student[i] == 'A' and teacher[i] == 'A':
    sum = sum + 1
elif student[i] == 'B' and teacher[i] == 'B':
    sum = sum + 1
elif student[i] == 'C' and teacher[i] == 'C':
    sum = sum + 1
elif student[i] == 'D' and teacher[i] == 'D':
    sum = sum + 1
elif student[i] == 'E' and teacher[i] == 'E':
    sum = sum + 1
else:
    sum = sum
```

print(sum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the for loop while getting input you have to store it in an array but in your case your are storing it in a string, so whenever the for loop iterates instead of appending the values it replaces the old value. To get the correct result you have to correct the following steps. And their needs a minor improvement in your final for loop to get correct sum value.

```
n = int(input())
sum = 0
student = []
teacher = []

for s in range(n):
   student.append(input())

for t in range(n):
   teacher.append(input())


for i in range(len(student)):
   if student[i] == teacher[i]:
      sum = sum + 1
```

Try this code and comment your result.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. More importantly, thank you for explaining the logic error.

Comment: @JunTsuru can you upvote my answer, so it can reach as many as possible. Thanks.

Comment: I did. I’m pretty new so I still need more reputation to case a vote but I did vote up